# ASP.Net page showing default IIS page

Tags: asp.net, iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using the `AWS Toolkit` for `Visual Studio 2013 Community` to set up an ASP.Net website at Amazon EC2. I created the instance of the web app in `elastic beanstalk` supposedly connecting to my instance of Windows Server 2012 with Webserver installed and started.

When I go to the website page it shows the default IIS info page. On my server instance I deleted the default web site in trying ti fix it. Was this a big error? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong or missing. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what problem do you have?

Comment: When I click the elasticbeanstalk page for my app it's showing the the IIS info page, not my app. The AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio says it's using an S3 bucket. I guess it's not using my EC2 Windows Server, is it?

Comment: I still didn't understand your problem. If you can see the default IIS page, it means web service is running web on that host. Then you need check the IIS config if it is pointed to the right folder to display the web content.